# Are there any security issues or vulnerabilities by adding or using some open source visual studio extensions?

Tags: visual-studio, security, visual-studio-extensions

There are very helpful visual studio extensions available. Are there any security issue or vulnerabilities by adding or using them into visual studio? I am using visual studio 2015. if threats will be there, then provide some suggestions.

Comment: What is the security issue or vulnerabilities? Maybe you could share a sample, so we could understand it better. For example, if you want to  use certain tool to analyze the code rules or Code performance, you could use the code analyze tool or Debugger Diagnostic tool.

Comment: example vs extensions are indent guide, codemaid. How do I ensure that these extensions are safe to use in VS2015.

Comment: I didn't find any security issue for that extension, but my understanding is that it would not have the security issue, because marketplace site would have its own requirements, in addition, the community members could report this issue to the extension tool under Q & A or other ways even if it has certain limitations more or less, So the code author could update it in time. Of course, as a developer, if you want to write custom extension, it also has the best practices for Security:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166442.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply :-), got enough info from your ans.

Comment: You are welcome, I add it as the answer. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add the solution:**

(1)If you want to use the extension tool of the marketplace site. I didn't find any security issue for it, I often use some of them, they are safe.

Since marketplace site would have its own requirements, in addition, the community members could report this issue to the extension tool under Q & A or other ways even if it has certain limitations more or less, So the code author could update it in time. SO I think the extension tools are safe.

(2)If you want to write custom extension, it also has the best practices for Security:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166442.aspx

Of course, if you find any safe or other issues for any extension tools from the marketplace, you could ask the issue here, I will help you repro this issue using the same Environment as yours.